# Earthquake database for fault

Tags: earthquakes

I am trying to understand Deterministic Seismic Hazard analysis for which I believe seismic waves corresponding to a seismic sources (such as faults) are required to prepare the Gutenberg Richter curve and select an appropriate earthquake corresponding to a particular return period. However I do not know from where I can obtain the seismic data?

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, you can try at [OpenData.se] (But do not post on both sites at the same time, [crossposting across SE sites is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [Global Significant Earthquake Database request form](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/nndc/struts/form?t=101650&s=1&d=1) from NOAA would help?

Comment: Also:

http://www.opendtect.org/osr/ and http://ds.iris.edu/data/sources.htm

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in the same topic. Recently, research on the determinism behind earthquake triggering has been revived based on these studies from last year:

1. Ide, Satoshi, Suguru Yabe, and Yoshiyuki Tanaka. "Earthquake potential revealed by tidal influence on earthquake size-frequency statistics." Nature Geoscience 9.11 (2016): 834-837.
2. van der Elst, Nicholas J., et al. "Fortnightly modulation of San Andreas tremor and low-frequency earthquakes." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences (2016): 201524316.
3. Delorey, Andrew A., Nicholas J. van der Elst, and Paul A. Johnson. "Tidal triggering of earthquakes suggests poroelastic behavior on the San Andreas Fault." Earth and Planetary Science Letters 460 (2017): 164-170.

A few years before these results were published, another seismologist did an extensive evaluation:

> "Characteristics of the earthquake-triggering pattern by Earth tides were studied utilizing over five hundred thousand events from an earthquake catalogue (NEIC-USGS) for global earthquakes with a magnitude range of 2 to 10."  -- Vinayak G. Kolvankar, "Sun, Moon and Earthquakes", New Concepts in Global Tectonics Newsletter, no. 60, September, 2011.

He was able to find correlations such as this:
[image]

So the best bet is to look at the [NEIC-USGS database](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/data.php).   You should be able to cull from quite a few events across the intensity spectrum.